# libgit2sharp repository credentials

Tags: c#, vb.net, git, libgit2sharp

I'm using LibGit2Sharp to clone a repository into a local folder. I know I could simply use Brute Force and delete the .git folder afterwards, and that will certainly achieve what I set out to achieve, but it's not the most elegant way to address this. If I deleted the .git folder I would have to clone it again at a later stage. I want to easily "switch" between branches but it becomes a slow and laborious process if every time I have to re-clone it before I can do that.

What I would like to do is to, after Cloning the repository, .... and here is where I don't know the correct terminology. what.... "log out"? "disconnect the credentials"? I don't know. Basically, what I want to achieve is that after the Clone a user cannot simply go and start messing about with the files and Push them back up to the remote repository, but I can't find any clear answers online about how to "clear credentials". I'm looking to do so programmatically, obviously.

Sorry. As this isn't clear in my own head I don't know how to ask this properly. I hope I described it clearly enough for someone to know how to answer this.

Answers in C# or VB.NET welcome ...

Regards

Pino

Comment: Is the user in the same process, or are you talking about a normal interactive user of the Git repository running other processes?

Comment: I thought about this over the weekend and perhaps I'm being silly. I wrote an assembly that uses LibGit2Sharp to get files from a remote repository. To do this I use a particular set of credentials. When I do this on my machine, on which I have TortoiseGit installed, I then see the green tick against the folder. What I am worried about is whether TortoiseGit would then use the same credentials that I used in my own Assembly, or would TortoiseGit expect the user to use his or her own?

Comment: So I got my hands on a second machine on which I installed git and tortoisegit. It asked me for credentials which I refused to enter (you can carry on without doing that). I then ran my software and it got the files out of the repository using the coded credentials. After that I added a file to the folder and tried to commit, and TortoiseGit demanded credentials. In other words, I was unable to commit/push changes from this "client" PC. Which is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Happy days, so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to "log out" in any way, shape or form. The remote repository remains inaccessible without credentials, even if the user installs GIT or TortoiseGit or some such. So I worried for no good reason.